# Error al abrir terminal mac

Tags: terminal

Cada que Abro la terminal me aparece este error y no lo puedo quitar, alguien sabe que puedo hacer para que deje de aparecer?

> -bash: export: `=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Visual
>   Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio
>   Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio
>   Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin': not a valid identifier
>   -bash: code: command not found
>   -bash: export:`Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual': not a
>   valid identifier
>   -bash: export: `Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual': not a
>   valid identifier
>   -bash: export:`Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio
>   Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin': not a valid identifier
>   -bash: export: `Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual': not a
>   valid identifier
>   -bash: export:`Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual': not a
>   valid identifier
>   -bash: export: `Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio
>   Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin': not a valid identifier
>   -bash: export:`Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin': not a valid identifier